# Nginx Config For React and Node App Proxying to Wrong Path

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, node.js, application-server

I've setup a server with an Nginx config for a React frontend and Node backend.

The Node app serves as an API for the react app.
The node routes for /api/... are getting passed to the following path: /client/public/api/...  This results in a 404.

I understand what may be adding this, I assume the root definition has the /client/public/ path definition. But cannot find a solution around it with the Nginx Config, attached below.

The /client/public/ part of the path string should not be in the uri of the request URL.

```
server {
  listen                80;
  server_name           www.domain.com;

  root                  /var/www/site_folder/client/public;

  index                 index.html;

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log          off;
    expires             max;
  }

  location /api/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:5000;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny                all;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following location block:

```
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    }
```

**Do not miss the trailing slash of the `proxy_pass` directive parameter!** You can find description of this construction behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx/53650827#53650827).

Comment: So when Implement this I get the following in my error log:
`[error] 27124#0: *1 open() "/var/www/example.com/client/public/api/session" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 104.190.138.77, server: www.example.com, request: "POST /api/session HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"`

Comment: @JohnFasano Maybe I misunderstand your question. I thought your API requests looked like `example.com/client/public/api/some/path` and should be routed to `localhost:5000/api/some/path`. Are they looked like `example.com/api/some/path` and should be routed to `localhost:5000/some/path`?

Comment: The node app is in a /server/ folder, but when defining the domains root within /client/public/, the API calls are coming from /client/public/api/path. 
Both the /server and /client are at the same directory level.

Comment: The request should be localhost:5000/some/path

Comment: @JohnFasano Try the updated config, please.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked! THANK YOU!